# Fill a Column for Every Row in a Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I just added a new column to a table which has over 1000 rows of data. I am wondering how I can update the new column with a piece of data for all of the rows in the database without having to manually do it.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

I am working with a MS SQL 2005 server. Thank you in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this out.

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value
```

This is given that the value you want to assign is a constant.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     newcolumn = 'newvalue'
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to set several values:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = value1, other_column_name = value2;
```